# what is wrong with parsing my data from json in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to update the `UITableView` with data fetched from Alamofire. 
My backend webservice returns the data as follows:

```
{"hashtags":["test","test2"]}
```

and my 'swift` code for that looks like this:

```
Alamofire.request("\(serverURL)/users/\(username)/hashtags")
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
switch response.result {
            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

    if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

    for hashtag in jsonData {
        print(JSON(hashtag))
        print(hashtag)
        if let userHashtags = SingleHashtag.fromJSON(JSON(hashtag)){

        for hash in userHashtags.hashtagText {
            print(hash)
            self.items.add(hash)
```

Function `SingleHashtag.fromJSON` is part of the class:

```
class SingleHashtag: NSObject {

    var hashtagText: [String]

    init(hashtagText: [String]) {
        self.hashtagText = hashtagText
        super.init()
    }

    class func fromJSON(_ json: JSON) -> SingleHashtag? {
        let hashtagText:[String] = json["hashtags"].arrayValue.map { $0.stringValue}
        return SingleHashtag(hashtagText: hashtagText)
    }


}
```

and I cannot make it work. The problem is that those two lines:

```
print(JSON(hashtag))
print(hashtag)
```

print:

```
unknown
("hashtags", <__NSArrayI 0x170c22200>(
test,
test2
)
)
```

and because I'm passing `unknown` there, the rest of the code is not executed. What did I miss here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON appears to be a dictionary who's only key contains an array of strings.

You are trying to loop through your dictinionary as if it's an array. That's wrong.

Try using 2-step optional binding like this:

```
if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject],
      hashtags = jsonData["hashtags"] as? [String]  {
    for hashtag in hashtags {
      //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Duncan, I tried your solution, but I'm getting this error http://imgur.com/a/X0HVm seems like I cannot make 2-step binding...

Comment: The syntax changed between Swift 2 and Swift 3 and I can never remember which is correct. The screen-shot you posted shows you exactly how to fix it. See if you can work it out from that.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the structure of your Json data is going to be a dictionary with an array of strings as its value (`[String: [String]]`), you should cast it as such, instead of casting it as `[String: AnyObject]`.

Then, you can loop over the array contained in the dictionary and expect to have the string value.

```
    if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [String: [String]] {

        for hashtag in jsonData["hashtags"] {
            print(hashtag)
            // and so on
        }
    }
```